# PyQt4: scroll a message horizontally

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I want list message to scroll horizontally (right to left) to visible the whole text. My simple code is given bellow. But it's not working. what modification I have to do to make it working.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

self.my_list = QtGui.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
self.room_no.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("my_list"))
self.my_list.addItem("Hello this is scroll message in pyqt4")
item = self.my_list.item(0)
self.my_list.setItemSelected(item, True)
self.my_list.scrollToItem(item)
```

Comment: You could explain it better, a good option would be to show an image of your problem, and another where you show what you want to get.

Comment: It sounds like they want marquee text in a list widget. Is that correct @Akash

Comment: I think what he wants is the QListWidget to have horizontal scrollbar so he will be able to see long items.

Comment: I want marquee text in QListWidge @ZackTarr

Comment: I found a way to do it in a label but not the list. [Label example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827237/scrolling-text-in-pyqt). But I dont think it will be possible in the way they did it as it does it by changing the x,y of the label.